# bukkit - How to use a variable on config.yml?

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft, bukkit

i'm pretty new to Bukkit's config API, so I have a question: How to set a string on the YAML file containing something like %player% that would represent the player (for instance a broadcast when someone uses a command containing the sender's name that can be configurated). How to parse sender.getDisplayName() into %player% in config.yml?

My code right now is:

```
String message = core.getConfig().getString("message"); //Get the message from the config file
            message = message.replace("%player%", player.getDisplayName()); //Replace %player% with the player's name.
            ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message);
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(message);
```

My config.yml is:

```
message: &6%player% just launched the cow party!
```

The errors are:

http://pastebin.com/8AdA5Xe1 (so long)

Comment: Use string replace method, explain your question better

Comment: What else should I say? I want to tell the code that %player% in the config.yaml string is sender.getDisplayName() @Kerooker

Comment: the way you wrote your question, i simply couldn't understand what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is get the string from the `config.yml` file, and after that you need to replace the %player% with the player's name or display name.

Something like this would work;

```
String message = getConfig().getString("path.to.string"); //Get the message from the config file
message = message.replace("%player%", player.getName()); //Replace %player% with the player's name.
ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message); //Translate colors to color codes
player.sendMessage(message); //Send the message
```

You can also use this one-liner:

```
player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', getConfig().getString("path.to.message").replace("%player%", player.getName()));
```

You need to replace `player` with your a valid player of course.

Regarding your error:

You need to put quotation marks (") around your message, so change

```
message: &6%player% just launched the cow party!
```

into

```
message: "&6%player% just launched the cow party!"
```

Comment: I would say, cut the logic up in steps, it makes it easier to read and understand for others and maintain in the future. If you want I can edit your post for you.

Comment: Oh Thanks! I'll test it and will then accept as answer, thank you

Comment: @bramhaag And what should I do to use alternate & color codes with that method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution for the argument calling, should be used not only specific arguments by replacing it, for the long term solution should be like this, and str indicate as the parameters from yaml:

```
ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', str.replace(StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "%", "%"), msg_config.getString(StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "%", "%"))).replace("%",""));
```